# Contravariant Components (Susskind's book)

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vectors

In  his book about SR & classical field theory, Susskind generalizes from the differential of $X'$ (function differential) to any 4-vector. I got stuck there trying to figure out why it is possible and why this for holds for any general 4-vector?

$$ d(X')^\mu = \frac{\partial(X')^\mu}{\partial X^\nu} dX^\nu \tag{4.16} $$

$$ (A')^\mu = \frac{\partial(X')^\mu}{\partial X^\nu} A^\nu \tag{4.19} $$

The quote is:

> "Let’s abstract from this exercise a general rule for the transformation of 4-vectors. Going back to Eq. 4.16, let’s replace 4-vector components $d(X′)^ μ$ and $dX^ν$ with $(A′)^μ$ and $A^ν$. These represent the components of any 4-vector $A$ in frames related by a coordinate
> transformation."

Comment: Integrate eq (4.16) on both sides. For simplicity assume $\int d(X')^\mu = (A')^\mu$ and likewise for the unprimed frame. Keep in mind that the components are scalar. What do you get?

Comment: @SongofPhysics can you please elaborate?

Comment: exactly what do you want me to elaborate on?

Comment: @SongofPhysics just how do you integrate? more specifically, how to integrate when you have a sum with different differentials on the rhs?

Answer (score 1):

> I got stuck there trying to figure out why it is possible and why this for holds for any general 4-vector?

In this context $(4.19)$ is the **definition** of a $4$-vector: An assignment of $4$-tuple to each chart such that the coordinates w.r.t to two different charts are related through $(4.19)$. It is possible to define an [affine structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) on Minkowski space and then you can interpret the tuples as the representations of a vector w.r.t. to different bases. I can give more details if you are interested.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand most of what you're saying (my knowledge is only several undergrad courses), so more details will be good. Isn't the definition of 4-vector simply a vector that Lorentz transforms? 4.19 seems more general.

Comment: @SteveJolt "4.19 seems more general" - Given a differentiable manifold,  two charts with the same domain and a **vector field** on the said domain, we can consider the representation of the vector field w.r.t. both charts. Then 4.19 is the relation between both representations. But the section is about $4$-vectors, not about vector fields on a differentiable manifold.

Comment: "Isn't the definition of 4-vector simply a vector that Lorentz transforms?" - I would like to emphasize that a 4-vector is coordinate-independent and lives in a 4-dim. real vector space. The representation of a 4-vector w.r.t. a set of coordinates - a list of 4 real numbers - Lorentz transforms.  The crucial point is that we can interpret the real numbers as the coordinates of the vector w.r.t. a basis of $V$. Do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks but I guess I was hoping for a much simpler answer :) No idea yet about manifolds, charts, affine structures etc. I do understand 4.16 is the differential of X' and I thought I'm missing something simple in the generalization of 4.16 to 4.19.

Comment: @SteveJolt Yes, 4.16 can be interpreted as the differential of $X'$ as a function of $X$. But I do not think that this is the point and in fact there is a good reason that Susskind uses the term "infinitesimal interval". Let $e,e'\in M$ be two events in Minkowski space, then the difference $x(e')-x(e)$ w.r.t. a chart $x$ transforms like a vector (because the transition charts are assumed to be Poincaré transformations). This is precisely the reason why we can define an affine structure on Minkowski space.